# How to find the biggest contour of my image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have been searching for a method that can search the biggest contour of an image. I have been working in a program that can detect a hand, but in the images sometimes there are some blobs or detect some small object. I have try some methods like searching with `cv2.contourArea` and `cv2.arcLength()` but it didn't work in my code.

this is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter

def SkinColorUpper (Hue,mult1,mult2):
    upper = [Hue,mult1*255,mult2*255]
    upper = np.array(upper)
    return upper

def SkinColorLower (Hue,mult1,mult2):
    lower = [Hue,mult1*255,mult2*255]
    lower = np.array(lower)
    return lower

direc = ('Fotos/A/1.jpg')
img = cv2.imread(direc,1)
# cv2.imshow("Imagen",img)
# cv2.waitKey(0)
heigth, width = img.shape[:2]
#print (img.shape)

start_row,start_col = int(0),int(0)
end_row, end_col = int(heigth), int(width*.3)
img = img[start_row:end_row,start_col:end_col]

hls = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)

mask = cv2.inRange(hls,SkinColorLower(0,0.2,0),SkinColorUpper(27,0.72,0.75))
#mask = cv2.inRange(hls,np.array([0,49,61]),np.array([20,255,127]))

blur = cv2.medianBlur(mask,5)

ret,edges = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
#edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_CHRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
edges= cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
draw = cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,(255,0,0),3)
#print(contours)
cv2.imshow("mask",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

for component in zip(contours,hierarchy):
    current_contour = component[0]
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(current_contour)
    p = cv2.arcLength(current_contour,True)
    epsilon = p*0.015
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(current_contour,epsilon,True)
    lados = len(approx)
    empty = np.zeros((h,w),np.uint8)
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),1)
    roi = edges[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    empty[0:h,0:w]=roi
    edges=empty
    cv2.imshow("Edges",edges)
    cv2.waitKey(0)  
    img_resize = cv2.resize(edges,(150,150),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    ret, edges_res = cv2.threshold(img_resize,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv2.imshow("img_resize",img_resize)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    contours_2,hierarchy_2 = cv2.findContours(edges_res.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    for component_2 in zip(contours_2,hierarchy_2):
        currentContour =  component_2[0]
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(currentContour)
        M = cv2.moments(currentContour)
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        A = cv2.contourArea(currentContour)
        p = cv2.arcLength(currentContour,True)
        aP=A/float(p*p)
        #print(M['m10'],M['m01'],M['m00'],cx,cy,A,p,aP)
        Hu = cv2.HuMoments(M)
        # print(Hu)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So, I want to know how i can find the biggest contour to avoid those blobs

Comment: if the desired contour is extracted correctly you can.use contourArea or boundingRect or minAreaRect for example (depending on your definition of "biggest"). If the contour isnt extracted correctly you'll need more advanced techniques than thresholding and morphology... Can be a very hard problem to solve.

Comment: Thanks! I have solved the problem with the help from a friends.